# double lines in listview c# uwp

Tags: c#, xaml, uwp

I'm trying to solve this problem but I was not able to find a solution..
I have a dictionary(key, value) as this:

```
 private Dictionary<string, string> myDictionary = new Dictionary<string, string>();
```

this dictionay is filled with some values (string, string), in this way:

```
   private void LoadData()
    {
        myDictionary = FillMyDictionary();
        foreach (var str in myDictionary)
        {
            myDictionayList.Items.Add(str.Key);
        }
    }
```

In the Xaml file I show the dictionary in a listview like this:

```
        <ListView x:Name="myDictionayList" Margin="0,25,0,0" HorizontalAlignment="Center" VerticalAlignment="Center" Width="250" Height="640" FontSize="12" IsDoubleTapEnabled="False" IsHoldingEnabled="False" IsRightTapEnabled="False" IsTapEnabled="False" IsEnabled="False" IsHitTestVisible="False" Background="Transparent">
            <ListView.ItemContainerStyle>
                <Style TargetType="ListViewItem">
                    <Setter Property="HorizontalContentAlignment" Value="Center"/>
                    <Setter Property="MinHeight" Value="25"/>
                </Style>
            </ListView.ItemContainerStyle>
        </ListView>
```

In this way I'm able to show the key values of my dictionary in the ListView. Now, I would like to add a second row where I put also the Value of the dictionary, obtaining something like this:

[image]

thanks for your suggestions

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you meant myDictionayList.Items.Add(str.Key) in your question's code.

Are you looking for something like this?

```
<ListView x:Name="myDictionayList" Margin="0,25,0,0" HorizontalAlignment="Center" VerticalAlignment="Center" Width="250" Height="640" FontSize="12" IsDoubleTapEnabled="False" IsHoldingEnabled="False" IsRightTapEnabled="False" IsTapEnabled="True" IsEnabled="True" IsHitTestVisible="False" Background="Transparent">
        <ListView.ItemContainerStyle>
            <Style TargetType="ListViewItem">
                <Setter Property="HorizontalContentAlignment" Value="Center"/>
                <Setter Property="MinHeight" Value="25"/>
            </Style>
        </ListView.ItemContainerStyle>
        <ListView.ItemTemplate>
            <DataTemplate>
                <Grid>
                    <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                        <RowDefinition/>
                        <RowDefinition/>
                    </Grid.RowDefinitions>
                    <TextBlock Text="{Binding Key}" Grid.Row="0"></TextBlock>
                    <TextBlock Text="{Binding Value}" Grid.Row="1" Foreground="Gray"></TextBlock>
                </Grid>
            </DataTemplate>
        </ListView.ItemTemplate>
    </ListView>
```

Then you can simply add the dictionary item to the myDictionayList listview and style each row however, I just set it as gray.

```
        foreach (var str in myDictionary)
        {
            myDictionayList.Items.Add(str);

        }
```

Comment: mmm not exacly...I would like to add the second row as a description of the first row (like the image that I posted). According to your answer, instead, key and value are two different lines.

Comment: I edited my answer to use XAML data binding and grid rows.  Is that what you're looking to try and do?

Answer (score 1):

You can do that easily by editing the `ItemTemplate` of the list view and adding `StackPanel` in that like this:

```
<ListView x:Name="MyListView">
    <ListView.ItemTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
            <StackPanel >
                <TextBlock Text="{Binding Key}"/>
                <TextBlock Text="{Binding Value}"/>
            </StackPanel>
        </DataTemplate>
    </ListView.ItemTemplate>
</ListView>
```

and the ItemSource of the `ListView` obviously goes to a dictionary in the code-behind:

```
MyListView.ItemsSource = new Dictionary<string, string>
{
    {"Item1", "Description1"},
    {"Item2", "Description2" }
};
```

which produces result like this:

[image]

I think this is what you want. Hope that helps.